# What does calling 'each' on a range inside a block do?

Tags: ruby

I'm supposed to define a method `substrings` that will return a hash listing the number of occurrences of substrings that match against a defined array of strings. Here is the code

```
dictionary = ["below", "down", "go", "going", "horn", "how", "howdy", "it", "i", "low", "own", "part", "partner", "sit"]

def substrings(sentence, dictionary)
  substrings = Hash.new(0)
  words = sentence.split(" ")
  words.each { |word|
    word = word.downcase
    characters = word.split("")
    length = characters.length
    (0...length).each { |start|
      substring = []
      (start...length).each { |stop|
        substring.push(characters[stop])
        if (dictionary.include?(substring.join))
          substrings[substring.join] += 1
        end
      }
    }
  }
  puts substrings
end

substrings("Howdy partner, sit down! How's it going?", dictionary)
```

I'm interested in this block of code

```
(0...length).each { |start|
```

I'm wondering what `each` method is called on. I don't see an array explicitly listed for the `each` method to be called on. There is a range listed, but how does it know what array the range is referring to? Does it just call it on the block it is currently in?

Comment: Look at it this way. `e = (3..9).each #=> #<Enumerator: 3..9:each>`. Ruby then uses the method [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to generate elements of `e`, which she passes to the block, assigning their values to the block variable `start`: `start = e.next #=> 3; start = e.next #=> 4` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length` is defined as:

```
length = characters.length
```

and `characters` is defined as:

```
characters = word.split("")
```

`word` is a block variable for an iteration over `words`, which is defined as:

```
words = sentence.split(" ")
```

In other words, `(0...length).each` iterates over each index of the characters in `word`, which is yielded by splitting `sentence` by a space.

Comment: Thanks! Just the explanation that I needed!

Comment: @MasonTowne another way to express `(0...length).each` is `length.times`

Answer (score 2):

> I'm interested in this block of code
>
> ```
> (0...length).each { |start|
> ```
>
> I'm wondering what `each` method is called on.

It is called on the [`Range` literal `0...length`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html).

> I don't see an array explicitly listed for the `each` method to be called on.

Why would there need to be an `Array` for `each`? There are lots of classes which implement `each`: [`ENV`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/ENV.html#method-c-each), [`ARGF`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/ENV.html#method-c-each), [`Dir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-each), [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-c-each), [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-each), [`IO`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-each), [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-c-each), [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Struct.html#method-c-each), [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-c-each), and that's just the ones in the core library. There's even more in the standard library, for example [`CSV#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-each) in the [`csv` library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/), [`Matrix#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-each) and [`Vector#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-i-each) in the [`matrix` library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/), [`REXML::QuickPath#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/QuickPath.html#method-i-each), [`REXML::XPath#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/XPath.html#method-i-each), [`REXML::AttlistDecl#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/AttlistDecl.html#method-i-each), [`REXML::Attributes#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/Attributes.html#method-i-each), [`REXML::Elements#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/Elements.html#method-i-each), [`REXML::Light::Node#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/Light/Node.html#method-i-each), [`REXML::Parent#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/Parent.html#method-i-each), [`REXML::Parsers::PullParser#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/Parsers/PullParser.html#method-i-each), and [`REXML::SyncEnumerator#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/SyncEnumerator.html#method-i-each) in the [`rexml` library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/), [`Set#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-each) in the [`set` library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/), [`StringIO#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html#method-i-each) in the [`stringio` library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/), [`YAML::DBM#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/DBM.html#method-i-each) in the [`yaml` library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/), and probably many more. And of course, there are probably hundreds of others in the wider Ruby ecosystem, e.g. there are 14 implementations of `each` in Ruby on Rails.

> There is a range listed, but how does it know what array the range is referring to?

It doesn't. The `Range` isn't referring to an array. It is referring to a range.

> Does it just call it on the block it is currently in?

You can't call methods on a block. You can only call methods on objects, and blocks aren't objects in Ruby. (You can reify a block, but then it becomes just a normal `Proc` object. And `Proc` doesn't respond to `each`, so you can't call `each` on that, either.)